# Meteor wallet app tutorial mins 9:27 - 12:12 Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, meteor, meteor-react

I'm using meteor js for a project and keep getting this error following the tutorial in meteor university.
for context i'm on the first project build meteor wallet app tutorial mins 9:27 - 12:12.
does this mean that i have to download typescript?:

Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use any type of annotation to follow Meteor University videos.

I think the misunderstanding is because Webstorm keeps showing *type hints* as annotations and this confuses some people. We should have disabled Webstorm hints for recording the course.